# Call a JavaScript function from a texbox that is generated by an MVC Helper

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How do I call a JavaScript function from a texbox that is generated by an MVC Helper. I want my textbox to call a function like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Ejemplo" onkeyup="SumaEjemplo()" />
```

I'm using:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Ejemplo") %>
```

Where do I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use event binding

By using jQuery you could write this code in Javascript (either directly inside a `<script>` tag or in a separate script file that's loaded with the view:

```
$(function(){
    $("#Ejemplo").keyup(SumaEjemplo);
});

function SumaEjemplo(eventInstance){
    // handle onkeyup event
}
```

This way you'll be able to attach multiple events to the same control and is considered **the proper way** of doing this.

Comment: Actually it's $("#Ejemplo").keyup(SumaEjemplo); without the "on"

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Ejemplo",string.Empty,new{onkeyup="SumaEjemplo()"})%>
```

Comment: -1 because it doesn't allow multi-event binding. Griegs answer is much better.

Comment: Wrong, it allows multi-event binding: Html.TextBox("Ejemplo",string.Empty,new{onkeyup="SumaEjemplo1();SumaEjemplo2();"})%>

Comment: And, with my method no need to rebind the events after a partial update

Answer (score 1):

You could also use jQuery to automatically bind the event when the control is created.  This is really only useful I guess when you want to create the controls within a javascript/jquery event.